# Another OpenGL SuperBible 5th edition set-up problems

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

Well, i have just bought this opengl superbible book (5th edition). Unfortunately, i stumbled upon on first chapter as how to set up the opengl itself. Here is the step that i did.

(1) First of all i installed **Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 C++ Express**.

(2) I downloaded the libraries needed, as for this i downloaded directly from the official site of opengl superbible : http://www.starstonesoftware.com/files/SB5.zip. Then i extracted the files into my local folder.

(3) And then i create new empty project. 
File -> New -> Project -> Visual C++ Installed Templates -> General -> Empty Projects

(4) Adding the additional include directories path for freeglut and gltools files header. 
Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> (then i set the configuration = All configuration) -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories. 
here i add two directories : 
(a) freeglut : [my local path]\SB5\freeglut-2.6.0\include
(b) gltools  : [my local path]\SB5\Src\GLTools\include

(5) Adding the additional dependencies path for also freeglut and gltools files header. 
Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> (then i set the configuration = All configuration) -> Linker -> Input -> Additional dependecies. 
(a)freeglut_static.lib
(b)GLTools.lib

(6) Adding the library directories. 
Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> (then i set the configuration = All configuration) -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories.
In here i set the locations of directories of freeglut_static.lib and GLTools.lib
(a)freeglut_static.lib : [my local path]\SB5\freeglut-2.6.0\VisualStudio2008Static\Release
(b)GLTools.lib : [my local path]\SB5\VisualStudio2008\GLTools\Release

(7) After that i copy the source code (Triangle.cpp) but **i didn't forget to include windows.h** at first line.

```
// Triangle.cpp
// Our first OpenGL program that will just draw a triangle on the screen.

#include <Windows.h>
#include <GLTools.h>            // OpenGL toolkit
#include <GLShaderManager.h>    // Shader Manager Class

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <glut/glut.h>          // OS X version of GLUT
#else
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
#include <GL/glut.h>            // Windows FreeGlut equivalent
#endif

GLBatch triangleBatch;  
GLShaderManager shaderManager;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Window has changed size, or has just been created. In either case, we need
// to use the window dimensions to set the viewport and the projection matrix.
void ChangeSize(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This function does any needed initialization on the rendering context. 
// This is the first opportunity to do any OpenGL related tasks.
void SetupRC()
{
    // Blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );

    shaderManager.InitializeStockShaders();

    // Load up a triangle
    GLfloat vVerts[] = { -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
                          0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f };

    triangleBatch.Begin(GL_TRIANGLES, 3);
    triangleBatch.CopyVertexData3f(vVerts);
    triangleBatch.End();
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Called to draw scene
void RenderScene(void)
{
    // Clear the window with current clearing color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLfloat vRed[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_IDENTITY, vRed);
    triangleBatch.Draw();

    // Perform the buffer swap to display back buffer
    glutSwapBuffers();
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main entry point for GLUT based programs
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    gltSetWorkingDirectory(argv[0]);

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Triangle");
    glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);

    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GLEW Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
        return 1;
    }

    SetupRC();

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

(8) After step 7 i build the project and everything still went smoothly. Here was the build result :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: superbible1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>GLTools.lib(GLBatch.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc90.pdb' was not found with 'GLTools.lib(GLBatch.obj)' or at 'C:\Documents and Settings\Tony\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\superbible1\Debug\vc90.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
1>GLTools.lib(glew.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc90.pdb' was not found with 'GLTools.lib(glew.obj)' or at 'C:\Documents and Settings\Tony\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\superbible1\Debug\vc90.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
1>GLTools.lib(GLShaderManager.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc90.pdb' was not found with 'GLTools.lib(GLShaderManager.obj)' or at 'C:\Documents and Settings\Tony\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\superbible1\Debug\vc90.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
1>GLTools.lib(GLTools.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc90.pdb' was not found with 'GLTools.lib(GLTools.obj)' or at 'C:\Documents and Settings\Tony\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\superbible1\Debug\vc90.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
1>GLTools.lib(GLTriangleBatch.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc90.pdb' was not found with 'GLTools.lib(GLTriangleBatch.obj)' or at 'C:\Documents and Settings\Tony\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\superbible1\Debug\vc90.pdb'; linking object as if no debug info
1>  superbible1.vcxproj -> C:\Documents and Settings\Tony\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\superbible1\Debug\superbible1.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

(9) The problem came when i run the program. I get runtime error. There was an alert dialog with this message :

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in superbible1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

When i choose to break the program, the cursor was stoped in this line :

```
   GLfloat vVerts[] = { -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
                          0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f };
```

Well if i change this code with another simple code (from opengl redbook). For example like this :

```
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL\glut.h>

void display(void)

{
    /* clear window */

     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 


    /* draw unit square polygon */

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
        glVertex2f(-0.5, 0.5);
        glVertex2f(0.5, 0.5);
        glVertex2f(0.5, -0.5);
    glEnd();

    /* flush GL buffers */

    glFlush(); 

}


void init()
{

    /* set clear color to black */

    /*  glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); */
    /* set fill  color to white */

    /*  glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0); */

    /* set up standard orthogonal view with clipping */
    /* box as cube of side 2 centered at origin */
    /* This is default view and these statement could be removed */

    /* glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);  */
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    /* Initialize mode and open a window in upper left corner of screen */
    /* Window title is name of program (arg[0]) */

    /* You must call glutInit before any other OpenGL/GLUT calls */
    glutInit(&argc,argv); 
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);  
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0); 
    glutCreateWindow("simple"); 
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();

}
```

The application can run well. So i thought maybe there was something wrong with the code or probably there was something that i miss. So anyone can help?

Comment: Did you try using `/NODEFAULTLIB:library` as it suggested?

Comment: No. i wasn't using it. Then i tried to rebuild it with /NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT (as suggested from the warning message) but then i still got the same error. So it handle one warning because of some sort of conflict in the library. But there were still some errors, all of them are because of pdb files missing from GLTools.lib (the same warning like the build result before). so is there still any solution for this? has anyone succeed in this?sorry, after all i'm still a newbie.

Comment: Hey, i tried this with another computer with windows seven and it worked. Well, do anyone know why?

Comment: Sorry I actually have no idea either about newer OpenGL versions or Windows programming. I just saw that warning and thought I would point it out. Nevertheless, it could be that the libraries that you downloaded have been built for Windows7, so if you go to its website, you might find one that is built for a previous version of windows API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GLfloat vVerts[] = { -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, ...` can't be the problem. butVisual's green debugging cursor show the NEXT line that will be executed, so I suspect that it's shaderManager.InitializeStockShaders(); that crashes.

I have no idea what this does, but it probably reads files... make sure it finds them. In particular, running the .exe directly from the Explorer from a directory that seems to make sense, depending on the contents of the zip.

Answer (score 1):

I am just starting on this as well.

If you are going to work through all the examples it is better to copy all the freeglut/GLTools *.h* and *.lib* files into the relevant directories of VC++2010.

You will still have to include the *windows.h* in the source and still have to specifically tell VC++2010 use *GLTools.lib*(Linker,Input,Additional Dependancies).

[This](http://cldoten.wordpress.com/2009/07/01/vs2008-fixing-the-warning-pdb-vc90-pdb-not-found/)
apparently explains how to get rid of all the pdb errors if they bother you.

Comment: Messing with Visual's dirs is a really, really bad idea